# Java - use wait() method until specific time reached

Tags: java, multithreading, wait

I have a thread that runs in the background of my program and detects when a deadline (set by user input at the beginning of the program) occurs. I have implemented this in a `while` loop and using the `sleep(1000)` method.

It all works ok, but I would like to change it over from using `sleep(1000)` to using `wait()` and `notifyAll()` to be consistent with the rest of my code, and to make the alert happen in real-time rather than lagging by a part of a second until the thread re-awakens.

Here is what I currently have

```
    //Retrieve current date and time...
    Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();

    //deadline not yet reached
    while(now.before(deadline))
    {
        try
        {
            //wait a second and try again
            sleep(1000);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException intEx)
        {
            //Do nothing.
        }

        //Update current date and time...
        now = Calendar.getInstance();
        //run loop again
    }

    ////////////////////////////
    ///alert user of deadline///
    ////////////////////////////
```

I have tried to change it over to use `wait()`, but had no success. Can anybody see a way of changing the existing code over to implement the methods I mentioned?

Thanks in advance,
Mark

Comment: Where does notifyAll get called? Why don't you just sleep the number of seconds you need, and not some arbitrary 1000?

Comment: notifyAll() doesn't get called at the moment, as there is no wait() call yet. At the moment it checks every one second because the deadline time is entered to one minute, and I've just been running it with a check every second. I'd like to use wait() instead to make it more accurate @matt

Comment: I don't understand how wait would make it more accurate. You should probably use sleep to the ms you need and not for 1 second. That way if it you were a couple milliseconds off on your check, you wouldn't wait a whole second, only the couple milliseconds. If you want to do it correctly use a ScheduledExecutorService.

Comment: both wait and sleep use the OS to perform the waiting, and one is no more accurate than the other. In fact wait is less accurate as it can wake surpriously whereas sleep doesn't

Comment: BTW You shouldn't ignore exceptions unless you know you can safely do so.  You shouldn't make the mistake of saying; I don't know what to do with the exception so I will pretend it didn't happen.

Comment: Re, _I would like to change it over from using sleep(1000) to using wait() and notifyAll()_  Why?  `Thread.sleep(n)` and `o.wait(n)` are meant for solving different problems.  You can use wait(n) as a substitute for sleep(n), but the only thing you will accomplish is to confuse, annoy, and alienate other programmers who try to read your code.  The reason is, programmers expect the _name_ of a function to tell them something about what you're trying to accomplish.  If they see `wait(n)` then they expect to find a `notify()` somewhere.  But if they see `sleep(n)` they know not to bother looking.

Answer (score 6):

So this question is, how can I use `wait` to act like `sleep`. If you want to use wait, you will have to use two threads. Use a [`ScheduledExecutorService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) ([Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/executors.html)).

```
 ScheduledExecutorService executor = newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
```

This can be done once and reused. Otherwise you have to shutdown the executor.

We'll set our deadline to be `x` minutes in the future, using [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) from the modern [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework ([Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html)).

```
final Instant deadline = Instant.now().plus(x, ChronoUnit.MINUTES);
```

Next we want to schedule a task so that our thread will wake in x minutes.

```
while(Instant.now().isBefore(deadline)){
    synchronized(deadline){    
        executor.schedule(
            ()->{
                synchronized(deadline){
                    deadline.notifyAll();
                }
            }, 
            Duration.between(Instant.now(),deadline).toMillis(), 
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS
        );
        deadline.wait();
    }
}
```

It is in a loop, just in case there is a spurious awake. It resubmits the task, just in case there was a spurious awake and in the meantime the other task completed and didn't wake the thread before the thread called wait again.

This above is a bit tongue in cheek. Really if you just used the following it would seem more ''realtime''.

```
long diff = deadline.getTimeInMillis()-now.getTimeInMillis();
if(diff>0)
    Thread.sleep(diff);
```

Answer (score 1):

From oracle documentation [page](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait-long-)

```
public final void wait(long timeout)
                throws InterruptedException
```

> Causes the current thread to wait until either another thread invokes the notify() method or the notifyAll() method for this object, or a specified amount of time has elapsed.

**Precondition:** *The current thread must own this object's monitor.*

*A thread can also wake up without being notified, interrupted, or timing out, a so-called spurious wakeup*. While this will rarely occur in practice, applications must guard against it by testing for the condition that should have caused the thread to be awakened, and continuing to wait if the condition is not satisfied. In other words, waits should always occur in loops, like this one:

```
 synchronized (obj) {
     while (<condition does not hold>)
         obj.wait(timeout);
     ... // Perform action appropriate to condition
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [wait(long timeout)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait-long-) method.

Comment: Hi there, how does this method work? Will it just wait until the deadline is reached, and then drop out of the while loop?

Comment: @marcuthh it does say what it does in the javadoc. Note this is for working with a lock. If you are not locking an object it doesn't make sense to `wait` on it.